# Connecting mysql database with Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a problem connecting database with Android app. I am trying to implement [this](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/) tutorial. Everything seems to be fine but I neither get any success not an error.

There is a button listener which on clicking does a post to a PHP file and gets the result. Here is the code for it:-

```
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
            //String valid = "1";
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/check.php", postParameters);
                String res=response.toString();
                Log.d("res:", res);

               // res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
                //error.setText(res);

               if(res.equals("1"))
                    error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                else
                    error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password"); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                un.setText(e.toString());
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the http post method:-

```
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        Log.d("postMethodReturn", result);
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP code is as below:-

```
<?php
$un=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['password'];
//connect to the db
$user = "xyz";
$pswd = "xyz";
$db = "mydb";
$host = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match  
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user = '$un' AND pass = '$pw'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) --> 0)  
echo 1;  // for correct login response  
else  
echo 0; // for incorrect login response  
?>
```

Is there any bug in the program? I tried logging the intermediate values of res (http response) in activity code and result in the execute post method, but nothing is being logged. Tried changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" and also into a publicly available webhost, with all the database environment, but no success. All these on emulator and with public host, tried with real device too. Server seems to be running when checked from browser. Database exists with the values. All services running (apache, mysql).

The main problem is that there is no error! Any suggestions what is going wrong? 
Couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: can you tell what the result is printed?

Comment: it always gives the output as 0 (incorrect login response) and unfortunately no logs where requested.

Comment: this tells that the prblm is php function not in android side...so check your php connection first

Comment: ok thanks. any suggestions on how i can check?
i have the php file under /var/www and i am able to see the index.html file from the browser which is in the same directory.

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes... enjoy having your DB pwn3d. Plus, where in the php language spec is the `-->` operator defined?

Comment: @MarcB: you caught it! `-->` seems never to exist in PHP! thanks a ton! i was sitting on this problem for the last 2 days! :-(

Comment: Hi i have the same code but it always prints wrong username or password do you know what to do.

Comment: @user1844638: I had the problem with syntax, refer the accepted answer. Doesn't that help u?

Comment: hi i got it am working on jelly bean so had to use async...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was `-->` in the PHP code. changed it to `==` or `>` and everything works fine!